# Indexing matrix with values from vector in theano

Tags: python, matrix, vector, indexing, theano

I'm working on a cost function in theano and faced the following problem:
I have a matrix M (say `[[3,4],[5,6]]`), a vector v (`[0,1]`) and I would like to get the vector of entries in M corresponding to the indexes contained in v (here `[3,6]`). Is there a command to do exactly that?

Edit: I ended up doing the following : M[T.arange(v.shape[0]), v], where T.arange(v.shape[0]) is just a vector which entries are integers in the range of the length of v. M needed to be indexed with a list of two vectors

Comment: I don't understand the nature of v. How does index [0, 1] correspond to output [3, 6]?

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
VecOut = [M[i][j] for i,j in enumerate(V)]
```

enumerate returns indices and vector values to i (row index) and j (value of vector component), which can be used to get corresponding values from matrix.

example:

[image]

Comment: tensors don't support iteration though